# Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to file ">&"

Tags: c, output-redirect

I've coded this up and I'm unsure how to get this to work any other way.
I would also appreciate example code of how to test its correctness.

Thanks for the help

```
dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but you need to do the two `dup2` calls in the opposite order.

```
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO);
close(fd);
```

Your code is equivalent to the POSIX shell syntax (which is available in all shells whose syntax is based on Bourne shell):

```
2>&1 >filename
```

which makes `stderr` go to the *old* `stdout` while redirecting `stdout` to the file.

Comment: Run a program that produces normal output and errors, and check that the file contains both.

Comment: For instance, run `ls existingfile nonexistingfile`

Comment: Well, "the shell" syntax is not totally accurate. Not all shells accept this syntax. If I well remember, csh does not.

Comment: @jdarthenay I've clarified that I'm talking about POSIX/Bourne shell syntax.